# Django reload current page without using path

Tags: django, request, reload

this is probably a noobie question.
I'm working on a Django project, after a request, I reload the page using:

```
return redirect('home')
```

Is there anyway to reload the current page without writing the url path? I don't need to specify it, since the page I need to reload is the one that is actually open.

Hope someone can help and sorry for easy english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code :

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
```

Your request contains the actual path so you can redirect to the same page without specifying explicitly

[Path Info Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path_info)